# I am trying to get the hour from a timestamp column using pyspark sql function hour but it returns an error "'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to get the hour from the cloud_timestamp column in a databricks notebook. I am getting a error when I used this hour(to_timestamp(col("cloud_timestamp") from a method: "'int' object is not callable".But the code works without any problem when it is executed in a separate cell.I am not sure what I am missing here

Method:

```
 def write_data(self,env,dt,file_list):
    status= True
    try:
      spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
      read_hourly_file = spark.read.parquet(*file_list)
      partitionDF = read_hourly_file.withColumn("dt",lit(dt)).withColumn("env",lit(env))
      new_df = partitionDF.withColumn("hour", hour(to_timestamp(col("cloud_timestamp"))))
      return new_df
    except  :
      print("error",sys.exc_info())
      return False
    return status 
Sample Data

|cloud_timestamp         |
+------------------------+
|2022-01-26T04:19:51.626Z|
|2022-01-26T04:20:03.528Z|
|2022-01-26T04:20:03.529Z|
|2022-01-26T04:20:03.529Z|
|2022-01-26T04:20:03.528Z|
|2022-01-26T04:20:03.528Z|
```

Schema

```
 |-- otherProperties: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cloud_timestamp: string (nullable = true)

**working cell:**

    from pyspark.sql.functions import hour
    df = partitionDF.withColumn("hour", hour(to_timestamp(col("cloud_timestamp")))).select("hour").show()
```

Comment: Do you by chance have a variable named `hour` or `col` somewhere?

Comment: @0x5453 you are right i had a variable name hour, that was causing the problem.Thank you so much.